# Checking client side ack delay

Tags: javascript, websocket, delay, roundtrip

I'm trying to measure the rtt of a tcp connection, but I've run into some problems. The rtt is measured by finding the tcp_info of the server socket through [getsockopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html). This metric is, sadly, strongly affected if the client uses [delayed acks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment), as this adds the delay between packets sent from the server to the measured rtt.

If I can ensure that the client is using delayed acks (ie. the standard Windows TCPAckFrequency of 2), I can figure out the "real" rtt programmatically. This isn't realistic, though, as the application is a demo (of tcp features) running in a web browser (Javascript/WebSocket), and I don't want to ask users to mess with their registry to get a web page working.

The only real possibility I can see of getting a good measurement is either 
1: set the tcp ack frequency on the client's socket (currently a WebSocket, this is not a requirement), or 
2: somehow find out whether the client is using delayed acks or not, and adjust the measurement accordingly.

The first solution is possible through setting TCP_QUICKACK, but I haven't found that possibility in any javascript-based tcp solutions (native WebSocket or Socket.io). Similarly, I haven't found any good way to check the client's setting. Any ideas?